# obj.hasOwnProperty(key) vs directly referencing using obj[key]

Tags: javascript, json

Lets say I want to check whether a property exists within an Object or not. I was looking at two methods:

> if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)) { /* do this */ }

OR

> if(object[key]) { /* do this */ }

Assuming that we'll never have `object = { key: false };`
What are the tradeoffs of using one over the other ?

Comment: Try it with `object = { key: false }` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: +1. Didn't think of that. But, my test case will never have that situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`object[key]` checks the entire object chain, including the prototype chain.

`object.hasOwnProperty(key)` checks to see if the `key` property is assigned directly to the object and does not look in the prototype chain.

So, which one to use depends upon which result you want.

See a simple demonstration using the `hasOwnProperty` property: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6zhv87rk/ which is on the prototype for an object.

---

You would typically use `object.hasOwnProperty(key)` when your `key` can be any arbitrary string and you want to make absolutely sure that it will never conflict with a built-in property on the Object prototype.  In fact, if you really want to protect yourself, you even use this `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)` so even the `hasOwnProperty` property could be used with your object.  Cases like this would be when you're using a Javascript object as a hash lookup or dictionary-type object with arbitrary key values.

You would typically use `object[key]` when you are not concerned about such a conflict because you know what types of keys will be on your object and you know they won't conflict because this version is just shorter and a bit easier to read.

Comment: Added some situations why you would use one over the other.

Comment: Thanks so much. Also, which would be faster ?

Comment: I don't know which would be faster.  As with all performance questions, you'd have to devise a meaningful test for your particular situation and measure the performance in several different browsers.